# Price of property prices in local currency for countries in Latin America

Tags: data-request, prices, real-estate, latin-america

I am working on a project thesis and I haven't been able to find this set of data, mostly because everything I do encounter are global indexes and for specific countries, and looking into each country's specific website to find it.

I'm looking for any kind of file that has property prices in local currency for countries in Latin America in the same table, so I can run a comparative analysis.